# How can I display movies and TVs side by side?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I　want to display Movies and TV side by side with django_bootsrap.
Movies left side TVs right side.
But I don't know how display Movies left side TVs right side.

I display Movies and TVs by django's for.
Below html code. I'm not still CSS.

```
<h1>TV Score_by</h1>
<div class="row">

    {% for m in movie %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m.poster_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            {% if not m.name %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.title }}</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.name }}</h5>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="card-text">{{ m.overview }}</p>
            <a href="/movie/{{ m.id }}/" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<h1>TV Score_by</h1>
<div class="row">
    {% for m in tv %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m.poster_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            {% if not m.name %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.title }}</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.name }}</h5>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="card-text">{{ m.overview }}</p>
            <a href="/tv/{{ m.id }}/" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/).

```
<h1>TV Score_by</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    {% for m in movie %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m.poster_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            {% if not m.name %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.title }}</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.name }}</h5>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="card-text">{{ m.overview }}</p>
            <a href="/movie/{{ m.id }}/" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<h1>TV Score_by</h1>
<div class="col">
    {% for m in tv %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m.poster_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            {% if not m.name %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.title }}</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ m.name }}</h5>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="card-text">{{ m.overview }}</p>
            <a href="/tv/{{ m.id }}/" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```